# Having consumer issues when RocksDB in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb, flink-cep, rocksdb-java

I have a job which consumes from RabbitMQ, I was using FS State Backend but it seems that the sizes of states became bigger and then I decide to move my states to RocksDB.
The issue is that during the first hours running the job is fine, event after more time if traffic get slower, but then when the traffic gets high again then the consumer start to have issues (events pilled up as unacked) and then these issues are reflected in the rest of the app.

I have:
4 CPU core
Local disk
16GB RAM
Unix environment
Flink 1.11
Scala version 2.11
1 single job running with few keyedStreams, and around 10 transformations, and sink to Postgres

some configurations

```
flink.buffer_timeout=50
flink.maxparallelism=4
flink.memory=16
flink.cpu.cores=4
#checkpoints
flink.checkpointing_compression=true
flink.checkpointing_min_pause=30000
flink.checkpointing_timeout=120000
flink.checkpointing_enabled=true
flink.checkpointing_time=60000
flink.max_current_checkpoint=1
#RocksDB configuration
state.backend.rocksdb.localdir=home/username/checkpoints (this is not working don't know why)
state.backend.rocksdb.thread.numfactory=4
state.backend.rocksdb.block.blocksize=16kb
state.backend.rocksdb.block.cache-size=512mb
#rocksdb or heap
state.backend.rocksdb.timer-service.factory=heap (I have test with rocksdb too and is the same)
state.backend.rocksdb.predefined-options=SPINNING_DISK_OPTIMIZED
```

Let me know if more information is needed?

Answer (score 1):

`state.backend.rocksdb.localdir` should be an absolute path, not a relative one. And this setting isn't for specifying where checkpoints go (which shouldn't be on the local disk), this setting is for specifying where the working state is kept (which should be on the local disk).

Your job is experiencing backpressure, meaning that some part of the pipeline can't keep up. The most common causes of backpressure are (1) sinks that can't keep up, and (2) inadequate resources (e.g., the parallelism is too low).

You can test if postgres is the problem by running the job with a discarding sink.

Looking at various metrics should give you an idea of what resources might be under-provisioned.

Comment: I was checking for backpressure in the Flink Dashboard and none of the operators has backpressure, at least that is  what the metrics said, but not sure if that is a 100% true. I have just 4 CPU cores, do you think is a good idea to increase the  parallelism? this `state.backend.rocksdb.localdir` is disabled right now. I can run the test with discarding Sink, but not sure if that will be the solution, but I will.

Comment: The rocksdb localdir defaults to /tmp.

Comment: Do you think to increase the parallelism is a good idea?

Comment: The backpressure monitor in the Flink Dashboard is not a completely reliable indicator; it might say things are okay when they are not. But did you check for backpressure in every subtask? If the Flink sources aren't keeping up with the input from RabbitMQ, then something is backpressured.

Comment: Yes, I did check every subtask and all were marked as "Ok". I will first increase the parallelism to 8 and see if gets better, if not I will disabled the sinks to see, it make senses to you?

Comment: By increasing parallelism I get higher CPU and Memory uses as expected I think, checkpoints are a bit bigger but should be expected too, but  in positive I have stable consumer and latency at the moment.